# Create hyperlink for different sheet with address in a cell below every 5th column

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

not exactly an expert at VBA, but I'm trying to achieve the following :

I have ~400 items listed in a sheet in the following manner : 38 rows from row 3 to 41, every 5th column (column A, column F, column K, ..., colum AY)

Each of these items has a tab associated with it and the corresponding sheet's address is written at an offset of 40 rows.

For example, cell `A3` has an item name and the corresponding sheet's address `1!A1` is in cell `A43`. The corresponding sheet's address is the result of an Index/Match formula `=IFERROR(INDEX(Orgs,MATCH(Liste!A3,Orgs[ORGANISMES],0),1)&"!A1","")` and shows the correct address.

I want to create hyperlinks that allow the user to click on the name and get to the corresponding sheet. I would use the `HYPERLINK()` function but those link do not appear to work once I export to PDF (while the ones using the Insert-> Link function do seem to work).

So far, here is what I have:

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

Dim Hype As String
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

Dim currCol As Integer, currRow As Integer

Sheets("Liste").Activate

For currCol = Columns("A").Column To Columns("AY").Column Step 5
    For currRow = 3 To 41
        Hype = ActiveCell.Offset(40, 0)
        If Len(Hype) = 0 Then Exit For
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:=Hype, 
TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell
     Next currRow
Next currCol

End Sub
```

The code runs, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks to @BigBen, I edited to :

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

Dim Hype As String
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

Dim currCol As Integer, currRow As Integer

Sheets("Liste").Activate

For currCol = Columns("A").Column To Columns("AY").Column Step 5
    For currRow = 3 To 41
        Hype = Cells(currRow, currCol).Offset(40, 0)
        If Len(Hype) = 0 Then Exit For
        Cells(currRow, currCol).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(currRow, currCol), Address:=Hype, TextToDisplay:=Cells(currRow, currCol)
     Next currRow
Next currCol

End Sub
```

That now gives me Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

When I look in the editor, it seems that everything works (Hype = "1!A1", Cells(currRow, currCol) show the right item)

Could it be that the value of Hype doesn't work because of the quotation marks?

Comment: `ActiveCell` should probably be `Cells(currRow, currCol)`?

Comment: That gives me invalid procedure call or agument

Comment: Sorrry, I can't figure out the formatting

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, I just did

Comment: When you get the error, and press "Debug", what line is highlighted?

Comment: Try `Address:=Hype.Address` and also try `Address:="", SubAddress:=Hype.Address`

Comment: @Toddleson originally the line highlighted was `Cells(currRow, currCol).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(currRow, currCol), Address:=Hype, TextToDisplay:=Cells(currRow, currCol)`
Now with the edits I get `Invalid qualifier` and the highlighted is the Sub line

Comment: Ohhhh! `Hype` is a string but you're taking the value of the range instead of the address. `Hype = Cells(currRow, currCol).Offset(40, 0).Address`. You need the `.Address` at the end of this line and then you can do `Address:=Hype`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the missing piece was that TextToDisplay didn't like being pointed to a cell. Changing it to Cells(currRow, currCol).Value fixed it.

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()

Dim Hype As String
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

Dim currCol As Integer, currRow As Integer

Sheets("Liste").Activate

For currCol = Columns("A").Column To Columns("AY").Column Step 5
    For currRow = 3 To 41
        Hype = Cells(currRow, currCol).Offset(40, 0)
        If Len(Hype) = 0 Then Exit For
        Cells(currRow, currCol).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(currRow, currCol), Address:=Hype, TextToDisplay:=Cells(currRow, currCol).Value
     Next currRow
Next currCol

End Sub
```